# Angular model not changed when clear Kendo DatePicker from js code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, datepicker

I have html 

And want to clear value when user press 'Delete' button

My code:

```
    var handleDateKeyDown = () => {
        $('input[kendo-date-picker]').each((i, el) => {
            $(el).keydown((ev) => {
                ev.preventDefault();
                if (ev.key === "Delete") {
                    $(el).data("kendoDatePicker").value(null);
                }
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
```

UI part works, this code clear kendoDatePickervalue, but model not changed, there is some simple solution to clear kendoDatePicker value AND angular model value? I can't use `$scope.Pile.Date = null;` because I want to bind this method to all datepickers on the page...

EDIT: Missed html below:

`<input kendo-date-picker k-ng-model="Pile.Date" ng-blur="Save()" />`

Comment: if you use angular may be you should add $scope.apply() call after "value(null)" ?

Comment: not working, I think because model (Pile.Date) wasn't changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is some kind of solution i can think of  (sure not the best)

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAwQZRL1a4Dczw1uOk6V?p=preview)
manually empty the model

```
        $('input[kendo-date-picker]').each((i, el) => {
        $(el).keydown((ev) => {
            ev.preventDefault();
            if (ev.key === "Delete") {
                $scope.dateString = null
                $(el).data("kendoDatePicker").value(null);
                $scope.$apply()

            }
            return false;
        });
     });
```

another solution:
add delete button handler as directive:

```
app.directive('del',function(){
 return {
 restrict:'A',
 scope:{ngModel:'='},
 link:function(scope,el,attrs){
   el.keydown((ev) => {

     scope.$apply(()=>{
       $(el).data("kendoDatePicker").value(null);  
       scope.ngModel = null;          

     })
   })
 }
}
})
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eAwQZRL1a4Dczw1uOk6V?p=preview)

Comment: You manually set model to null ($scope.dateString = null) this is not solution for my problem because I have few datepickers and don't know which model should be cleared..

Comment: if you are pressing button - are you want all the datepickers will be cleared at once? or the only selected one?

Comment: very nice solution, but it required ng-model="modelName" attribute for element, I'm using k-ng-model="modelName" for getting date in Date object and some UI preferences, it is possible to get this solution works with k-ng-model="modelname" attribute?

Comment: yes, just replace ngModel with kNgModel and it should work this way

Answer (score 0):

You may try `$scope.$apply()` before `return false;` to see if it works. jQuery's event trigger may not trigger the $diggest loop in Angular.

Comment: Just tried, not works as expected because model 'Pile.Date' value not changed as I said above...